# Как сохранить файл на сервере node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, multer

Формирую данные и отправляю так

```js
submitForm (newValue) {
 let FD = new FormData()
 FD.append('action', 'UPDATE')
 FD.append('params', JSON.stringify(OEWparams))
 if (this.oew_type === 'el_image') {
  newValue.forEach(function (item, index) {
   FD.append('p[index][0]', item.img)
   FD.append('p[index][1]', item.img_mini)
  })
 }
 for (let value of FD.values()) {
  console.log(value)
 }
 Api().post('settings', FD)
}
```

консоль

```html
UPDATE

{"edit_type":"el","el_object":"5cad5b7f9439b91b342d3663","pixel_id":"5c7defa9f3eb9d0efcc4b5a9","el_type":"5c5e951ec3d902119834af69","value_type":"image","new_value":[],"startIndex":0}

File {uid: 1558322638902, name: "2018-lexus-lx570-116-1526419489.jpg", lastModified: 1550452912986, lastModifiedDate: Mon Feb 18 2019 11:21:52 GMT+1000 (Владивосток, стандартное время), webkitRelativePath: "", …}

File {name: "blob", lastModified: 1558322829055, lastModifiedDate: Mon May 20 2019 13:27:09 GMT+1000 (Владивосток, стандартное время), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 82204, …}
```

Считываю так

```js
const multer = require('multer');
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, '/tmp/my-uploads')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
    }
})

const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('p')

app.all('/settings', (req, res) => {
 var action = req.body.action;
 if (req.body.hasOwnProperty('params')) {
        if (typeof req.body.params === 'string') {
            req.body.params = JSON.parse(req.body.params);
        }
        if (req.body.params.hasOwnProperty('edit_type', 'value_type')) {
            if (req.body.params.edit_type === 'el' && req.body.params.value_type === 'image') {
                req.body.params.new_value = req.body.imgs
                upload(req, res, function (err) {
                    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
                        // A Multer error occurred when uploading.
                        console.log(err)
                    } else if (err) {
                        // An unknown error occurred when uploading.
                        console.log(err)
                    }

                    // Everything went fine.
                })
            }
        }
    }  
})
```

**Но файлы не сохраняются, в чем проблема?**

Comment: `app.all('/settings', **upload**, (req, res) => {...})`. Если я правильно понял, то сама мидлварь нигде не отрабатывает. Написана, но не отрабатывает. Надо же её в параметры вставить. Не?

Comment: Изменил на app.all('/settings', upload, (req, res) => {, всё равно не сохраняется

Comment: А при переходе на роут, если в консоль вывести `req.files`, что-нибудь показывает? Или undefined?

Comment: выводит { p: { index: [ [Array], [Array] ] } } указал так app.all('/settings', (req, res) => {
    var action = req.body.action;
    console.log(req.files)

Comment: Нехорошая структура с этими многомерными массивами :) Ну дальше смотри `req.files.p.index[0][1]`,  лежит ли что-то там? Потому что кажется, что лежит. На работе нет проекта, который реализовывал мултер, дома на ноуте остался, не могу посмотреть как я делал. Но на первый взгляд, всё окей. Кажется, какая-то простецкая опечатка где-то. Незаметная.

Comment: console.log(req.files.p[0][0]) выводит объект файла.
{ fieldName: 'p[0][0]',
  originalFilename: '2018-lexus-lx570-116-1526419489.jpg',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\SWEET-~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\5N8zx734LONufVlW13ZG-a7H.jpg',
  headers:
   { 'content-disposition': 'form-data; name="p[0][0]"; filename="2018-lexus-lx570-116-1526419489.jpg"',
     'content-type': 'image/jpeg' },
  size: 282394,
  name: '2018-lexus-lx570-116-1526419489.jpg',
  type: 'image/jpeg' }
Т.е. файл передается? Как его сохранить?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93842/discussion-between-tasty-script-and-alex-sazonov).

Comment: Я не могу найти, в каком месте Вы их сохраняете?

Comment: destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, '/tmp/my-uploads')
    }